# I would like to handle error when the token has expired

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, jwt

I want to get refreshtoken by using conditional statement on error when accesstoken expires. But when I run my code and expire the accesstoken, I don't know where to handle the error.

My goal now is to get an error if the token has expired so that the error string is written to the console like this if(error){console.log("error")}.

So how can i fix the code?

this is The code in index.js checks whether the jwt token is valid.

(index.js)

```
    const JWTConfig = {
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      secretOrKey: "jwt-secret-key",
    };

    const JWTVerify = async (jwtPayload, done) => {
      try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ where: { snsId: jwtPayload.id } });
        if (user) {
          done(null, user);
          return;
        }
        done(null, false, { reason: "올바르지 않은 인증정보 입니다." });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        done(error);
      }
    };

    kakao();

    module.exports = () => {
      passport.use("jwt", new JWTStrategy(JWTConfig, JWTVerify));
    };
```

(auth.js)

```
    router.post(
      "/me",
      // auth,
      passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
      async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
        console.log("?????")
          res.status(201).json(fullUserWithoutPassword);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
          next(error);
        }
      }
    );
```

Comment: If user is not present and false in your `try, catch` you want to return an error, correct?

Answer (score 1):

The `passport.authenticate('jwt')` middleware apparently doesn't error out when the token is expired.

You can still pinpoint token expiration scenarios by passing `passport.authenticate()` a custom callback and inspecting its `info` argument - which will have a `name` property of `"TokenExpiredError"` in this case.

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('jwt', function(error, payload, info) {
    if(error) {
      return next(error);
    }
    
    console.log(info.name)   // output: "TokenExpiredError"

    res.status(201).json(//..);
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Look here for more information on the custom callback pattern:

http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/ (Custom callback section at the end)

Comment: However, even though the token does not expire, info continues to run.